# Echo value from array created using `fetchAll("select `name` from `classes`")`

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to echo an array value from an array that was created using the following code.
The data for the array is pulled from a MySQL table.

```
$names = $db->fetchAll("select `name` from `classes`");
```

This is what is stored in the $names variable

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Web Design ) [1] => Array ( [name] =>
>   Art History ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Gym ) [3] => Array ( [name] =>
>   English ) [4] => Array ( [name] => Biology ) [5] => Array ( [name] =>
>   3D Animation ) [6] => Array ( [name] => Tech Disc ) [7] => Array (
>   [name] => Math ) [8] => Array ( [name] => Dance ) [9] => Array (
>   [name] => Video Production ) [10] => Array ( [name] => Home Ec ) [11]
>   => Array ( [name] => Government ) [12] => Array ( [name] => Physics ) )

I'm attempting to echo a [name] value OR all [name] values, but I can't figure it out. I've tried the following....

```
<?php echo $names['name'];?>
```

returns nothing

```
<?php echo $names['0'];?> //AND\\ <?php echo $names[0];?>
```

Both return the string  Array

Can someone please help me echo a single value from the array?

**Example:** Web Design or Art History

Also can someone please help me echo all the values from the array?

**Example:** Web Design Art History Gym English Biology ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `<?php echo $names[0]['name'];?>`, `<?php echo $names[1]['name'];?>`, etc....

This is because your query function returns an array with all results in it.
In that array, each row returned is an array again. And each field is a key in that array.

Comment: nl-x, how should I create it so it isn't an array of an array? How should I modify **$names = $db->fetchAll("select `name` from `classes`");**? Thank you!

Comment: You can leave it like it is. And if you want it all in a single dimensional array, you can do `$names = array_column($names, 'name');` afterwards.

Comment: nl-x, is there a better or more efficient way to create the array with the name values?

Comment: @ToddBenrud You could write your own implementation of the `$db->fetchAll()` method. But why whould you? This is good enough.

Comment: @ToddBenrud If you reeaalllly just wanted to echo out all class names with a space in between, you could also try: `$names = $db->fetchAll("select group_concat(name separator ' ') as names from classes"); echo $names[0]['names'];` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Echoing a single value:

`echo $names[0]['name'];`

Echoing all values:

```
foreach ($names as $name) {
   echo $name['name'].' ';
}
```

Comment: kkhugs, That worked! Thank you very much. Quick question, is the `fetchAll` the right or best way to create the array form the mysql table? Thanks again.

Comment: Since it works this way, I'd say it is fine the way it is. If you would like to eliminate an extra step, try `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)`, assuming you are using PDO that is.